# Extract shapefile from scanned PDF map using Open Street Map?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, pdf, maps, extract

I am new to QGIS. I have a scanned PDF document containing maps of the Italian highway network development year by year from the 1920s to the 1990s (i.e. showing the pre-existent network in a given year and those segments added that year). For example, for the year 1973 it looks like this:

[image: 1973 highway network]

I also have an Open Street Map shape file which I filtered to only keep the highways which looks like this:

[image: qgis]

However, the Open Street map shapefile does not contain the opening year for each segment of highway. Would it be possible to extract multiple shapefiles (one for each year) from the PDF maps, perhaps by overlapping it with the Open Street Map shapefile using QGIS or R or any other software? The ultime aim would be to have an "opening year" column (for each segment of highway) in the Open Street Map shapefile.

Could you direct me towards useful resources on this topic? This would significantly reduce the amount of work needed for this task (the alternative would be to manually add a completion year date to each segment of the highway on QGIS).

Comment: Maybe vectorize the image from 1973, then convert to a line. Buffer the line and get all OpenStreetMap (OSM) features inside the buffer. Howerver, quite cumbersome, I guess. Other option: bring the OSM lines on top of the scanned map, then manually select all segements that correspond to the raster image.

Comment: Georeference one scanned map, then try to vectorize and extract the roads. If it is doable, figure out a way to iterate this process over all pdfs. I think it would probably be easier to flip through the pdfs and manually add the year to the osm lines